# View files in docker container

Tags: ide, docker

I created a docker container.  I can ssh into the docker container.  How can I view files in my docker container with a GUI (specifically the WebStorm IDE)?

*I'm running a MAC on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5.*

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern is to mount your source code into the container as a volume. Your IDE can work with the files on your host machine and the processes running in the container can see the files. [docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)

There might be a way to set up remote file access with WebStorm, but I'd recommend trying the other approach first.

Answer (score 1):

`docker run daemon -v /mycodedir:/mydockerdir {libraryname}/{imagename}` if you mount your work directory and map it to the directory running files in the container you will be able to edit and see them in Web Storm.